# How to pass a Rails route through an ember-CLI app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, nginx

I have a Rails app that has some controllers and views, but it also acts as the API back-end for an Ember-CLI app I have created. My problem is that I need to access a route that is defined in the Rails `routes.rb` but I believe the Ember-CLI app is preventing this route from being loaded in a web browser.

The Rails route looks like the following:

`refile_app        /attachments                              #<Refile::App app_file="/Users/myUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bundler/gems/refile-373d42114839/lib/refile/app.rb">`

Another Rails route that isn't loading in the web browser is:

`signup GET    /signup(.:format)                         users#new`

I need to be able to download an attachment, but I am unable to do so on the production box.

In my local dev environment I'm starting Rails with the following command:

```
rails s --binding 127.0.0.1
```

and I'm starting the ember-CLI app with the following command:

```
ember server --proxy http://127.0.0.1:300
```

In production, my `nginx.conf` looks like the following:

```
upstream puma_Kegcop {
  server unix:///home/user/apps/Kegcop/shared/tmp/sockets/Kegcop-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name kegcop.chrisrjones.com;

  root /opt/ember/kegcop-web-frontend/dist;

  access_log /home/user/apps/Kegcop/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/user/apps/Kegcop/current/log/nginx.error.log;

  # Proxy to our API
  location /api {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_pass  http://puma_Kegcop;
  }

  # UI, Ember app, Static Build
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you serving your app with Rails for Ember CLI (which only works in dev mode)?

Comment: @GJK please see the update I added to the question.

Comment: If you go to "<your-site>/login" directly, are you able to get to the page you want? Can you show me how you're generating the link that's not loading?

Comment: also can you share your router?

Comment: @mkirk I got this issue resolved about an hour ago, I'll post my updated `nginx.conf` in an answer, thanks for your inquiry.